# Using JavaScript to change were a link is pointing to based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a mobile-first site using the Bootstrap 4 framework. I am trying to create a JavaScript function which will change where a `<a>` tag is pointing to based upon the screen size of the browser. The following is just a very small portion of the HTML code for the page:

```
<div class="col-md">
    <div id="accordion" class="form-group text-dark mt-3">
        <!-- Cold Card -->
        <div class="card">
            <!-- Cold Temps -->
            <!-- Temps include Make line temps, Refrigerator temps, 
                 Freezer temps, and Beffet temps -->
            <div class="card-header">
                <a class="card-link" 
                   data-toggle="collapse" 
                   data-parent="#accordion" 
                   href="#cold" 
                   id="coldlink">
                    <h3>Cold Temps Management</h3>
                </a>
            </div>

            <!-- Cold Card -->
            <div class="collapse" id="cold">
```

I have been trying several different JavaScript functions, and the following is the most recent set of functions which I have used:

```
const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 767px)");

if(mq.matches) {
    document.getElementById("coldlink").href = "#cold";
} else {
    document.getElementById("coldlink").href = "cold.php";
}
```

From what I have read across many different sites, this code should change the `href` attribute of the element "coldlink" to `"#cold"` when the screen size is 767px or larger, and `"cold.php"` when it is smaller than 767px. Howerver, when I run this code (in the full page) and inspect the page using the developer tools, I get an error message saying "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null"

I have used the `.getElementById(...)` method in several other functions without getting this same error message so I do not know where I went wrong this time.

*if there is a way to change the `href` attribute using Bootstrap, I would be more than willing to give it a shot as I have not discovered how to do this yet*

Comment: If possible, create two links with different `href` values and classes and use CSS media queries to hide one based on screen size.

Comment: @Ihazkode: would this affect the column layout of the page?

Comment: Ana Houa's answer may work for you, because your code may be running _before_ the link that you are trying to modify exists in the DOM. Depending on the position of the javascript in your page, it might be running before the markup is interpreted and the DOM is built by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Add window onload, in order to let your DOMs in the page to completely load, than you can get your anchor element and change its href, if you want to do DOM manipulation with javascript, you better make sure that they are all loaded first.

```js
window.onload = function () {
            const mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches
            if (mq) {
                console.log('More')
                document.getElementById("coldlink").href = "#cold";
            } else {
                console.log('Less')
                document.getElementById("coldlink").href = "cold.php";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Explain what the problem is and why this solves it, and I'll upvote you. "Do this" doesn't help people learn.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an href on your  you can do an on-click event 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

In your onclick function you can do

```
const mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 767px)");

if (mq.matches) {
    window.location.href = "#cold";
} else {
    window.location.href = "cold.php";
}
```

Comment: This might work if part of the original code (which I am wanting to use when the screen is larger than 767px) was not an accordion, or would this suggestion still work with accordions?